# Durrett, probability textbook notation question $X_{N \wedge n}$ and $(H\cdot X)_n = X_{N\wedge n} - X_0$.

Tags: probability-theory

In the [text](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf) 'Probability: Theory and Examples', along theorem 5.2.5 to 5.2.6, the author uses the notation $X_{N\wedge n}$.

In the previous page, he defines $a \wedge b := \min(a,b)$.

My trouble is that $N\wedge n$ is a function (actually random variable), but it is used as an index of a function. Thus I cannot interpret $X_{N\wedge n}$. I want the precise definition of it.

And also, I don't think I understand $(H\cdot X)_n = X_{N\wedge n} - X_0$. What is $(H\cdot X)_n$? Is it $H_nX_n$?

Please HELP.

Comment: $$X_{N\wedge n}:\Omega\to\mathbb R,\omega\mapsto X_{N(\omega)\wedge n}(\omega)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X_{N\wedge n}$ is perhaps easier to understand if we make the dependence on $\omega$ explicit: it is the random variable $\omega\mapsto X_{N(\omega)\wedge n}(\omega)$.

In other words, it can be thought of as first evaluating the random variable $N$ at $\omega$ to obtain a non-negative integer, then computing the minimum $N(\omega)\wedge n$, and finally choosing the corresponding random variable $X_{N(\omega)\wedge n}$ and evaluating this random variable at $\omega$.

For the second question, Durrett defines
$$ (H\cdot X)_n=\sum_{m=1}^nH_m(X_m-X_{m-1}) $$
If $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 0}$ is a martingale and $\{H_n\}$ is a predictable process, then you can think of $X$ as the outcome of some fair game and $H$ as a betting strategy, and then $(H\cdot X)_n$ represents the winnings up to time $n$.

Comment: "it is the random variable $X_{N(\omega)\wedge n}(\omega)$. " Sorry but $X_{N(\omega)\wedge n}(\omega)$ is a number, not a random variable. The relevant random variable is $X_{N\wedge n}$.

Comment: Good point, I forgot $\omega\mapsto$